# Why is my list being altered by a function which only operates on the list copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object

So I have a list `D = [[1030, 1200], [1300, 1600], [1800, 1830]]` and I made a copy called E: `E = D[:]` then I tried to operate on it with a function: `covertToMin(E)`. However the function also operated on `D` which doesn't make sense because they have separate locations in memory.
I am pretty confused and appreciate any help!

```
    E = D[:]
    for i in range(len(E)):
        for j in range(0,2):
            E[i][j] = convertToMinutes(E[i][j])
    print(id(E))
    print(id(D))
    print(D)
    print(E)

def convertToMinutes(time):

    if time < 1000:
        time = str(time)
        minutes = time[1:]
        hourmin = int(time[0])* 60 

        time = int(minutes) + (hourmin)
    else: 
        time = str(time)
        minutes = time[2:]
        hourmin = int(time[:2]) * 60
        time = int(minutes) + hourmin
    return time
```

The output I receive is:

```
4368232032 
4368231552
[[690, 720], [900, 960], [1080, 1110]]
[[690, 720], [900, 960], [1080, 1110]]
```

Comment: For clarity you should consider posting simple versions of your questions even if i think the solution is simple here.

Comment: You need to do a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use python **deepcopy** for your problem. The [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) is clear and it will shed some light on it.

```
import copy
E = copy.deepcopy(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Python does not create a different list when you "equal" list variables (or dicts). To do that, you need to use `deepcopy()`

Try this in your code:

```
import copy

E = copy.deepcopy(D)
```

This will really generate two separate lists.

Comment: The slice notation `D[:]` does actually make a copy, it's the generally accepted way of doing it. The problem is that it doesn't make copies of the lists inside. The original code would have worked fine if it wasn't a list of lists.

Comment: Just to clarify the answer slightly, copy only do a shallow copy (same as `E = D[:]`), so elements in `E` and `D` refer to the same objects. I.e. `id(E[0])` and `id(D[0])` are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. That was something weird to me the first time I found this very same problem.